# How to return HttpResponseMessage when control goes to non returnable methods in ASP.NET WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WEB API application which call other .NET application method as below:

```
public override  async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(string receiver, HttpRequestMessage request)
   {
     try
          {

            Activity.Test();
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"Acitivity called" );   
           }


       catch (Exception ex)
            {
              return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ex.InnerException.ToString());
             }

    }
```

**Activity.Test** doesn't return anything and i can only call it.
Currently its working fine however i am getting internal server error status code 500 in fiddler.
Is there a way where we can return **HttpResponseMessage** with 200 status code if the control goes to  **Activity.Test()** ?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is Activity.Test method? Is it some action of the another controller?

Comment: @owczarek its a static method written in vb.net